# Are there indicators for overfitting?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

Do high values of regression coefficients indicate *automatically* that there is an overfitting?

Is there a way to know when we are overfitting our data?

Comment: Why would a high regression coefficient indicate overfitting?

Comment: From my understanding, in curve-fitting, when using least-squares regression, if the regression coefficients have high values it indicates that the model is trying hard to fit these coefficients to the data variation and this generates an overfitting.

Comment: What's the purpose of your regression analysis? You want to explain your data or you want to predict new values given inputs?

Comment: I want to explain data! Basically, I want to have coeff. that best explain my data and avoid overfitting (suppose I can detect that I have it.)

Comment: Try the "Copas test" for overfitting.

Answer (score 2):

No, specially as it depends on the scale of the input variables.

The indicative of overfitting is good performance in train set and bad generalization performance, meaning the learner *"memorized"* the train set, and this is assessed through resampling.

Comment: How do I test the generalization performance for curve-fitting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very simple.  Test your model on a Hold Out sample, a testing data set, or cross-validate it over numerous different Hold Out samples.  An overfit model is a model that fits the training sample very well but does not perform well over the various forms of Hold Out samples mentioned above.  If you are dealing with an econometrics model other indicators of models being overfit or badly specified include models that have a very high R Square (close to 1) and a very low Durbin Watson score (under 1.3 or so).  In such a case, your model has most probably a unit root in the dependent variable and in at least one of the independent variable (but your model is not cointegrate as your residuals are not stationary).  The easiest solution is to fully detrend all your variables.  Another indication of a model being overfit is when you have a really high R Square but some of your variables' coefficients are far away from being statistically significant.  In such a case, you have too many variables and you should eliminate the ones that have relatively weaker statistical significance.

Comment: I kind of see how is this applicable for classification but I'm dealing with curve-fitting overfitting and I can't see how can I check for this!

Comment: You are dealing with regression coefficients.  My advice is specifically catered to such a situation.